# Android Osmdroid bonuspack - change marker title after infoWindow action

Tags: android, osmdroid

Using Android Osmdroid Bonuspack I created a Marker with a custom InfoWindow.

```
marker = new MarkerWithLabel( mv, mapDescription6);
marker.setTitle( description); 
marker.setSubDescription( gcId); 
marker.setPosition( gp);
marker.setIcon( bubble); 
marker.setAnchor( 0.5f, 1.0f);
marker.setInfoWindow( new MapGeocacheAction( mv, this, gp, etc.));
```

In the InfoWindow I have a few buttons. When pressing one button, I would like to change the original Marker title (e.g. with a star behind then name).

How can I change the Marker title (real time) after clicking the button (so the InfoWindow is gone) to have a different name?

De MarkerWithLabel code is:

```
public class MarkerWithLabel extends Marker {
    Paint textPaint; 
    String mLabel; 
    public MarkerWithLabel(MapView mv, String l) {
        super( mv);
        mLabel = l; 
        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor( Color.RED);
        textPaint.setTextSize( dim25sp);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    }
    public void draw( final Canvas c, final MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {
        draw( c, osmv); 
    }
    public void draw( final Canvas c, final MapView osmv) {
        super.draw( c, osmv, false); 
        Point p = this.mPositionPixels;
        c.drawText( mLabel, p.x, p.y+20, textPaint); 
    }
```

}

**EDIT** using the solution from MKer:

1 - Getting the v5.1 version of Osmonuspack.

2 - In the WindowWindow add on a button click:

```
mMarkerRef.setTitle( title.substring( 2));
```

3 - In the MarkerWithLabel: use the title (not the label):

```
c.drawText( getTitle(), p.x, p.y+20, textPaint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your MapGeocacheAction inherits from MarkerInfoWindow.

MarkerInfoWindow keeps a handle to the Marker on which it has been opened, with mMarkerRef attribute. It is protected, so you have access to it in MapGeocacheAction.

So in your button click handler, before closing the window, you can set:

```
mMarkerRef.setTitle(newTitle);
```

Comment: After installing the Osmbonuspack v5.1 and Osmdroid 4.3 ... I saw the mMarkerRef visible. 

Changing the title has no visual effect so far. 
This is what I do: 

    mMarkerRef.setTitle( "*_" + eItem.getTitle());
    mMapView.invalidate();

Comment: As your InfoWindow is gone, marker title is not displayed anymore. Do you mean that after clicking your button, if you open your InfoWindow again, the title doesn't start with the "*_" ? Are you sure mMarkerRef.setTitle is called?

Comment: The title of the InfoWindow changed when I re-open it. 
The title on the Map beside the Marker has not changed. 

What I am looking for is that the title on the map (mapsforge) changes. 
How can I change that title on the map?

Comment: "The title on the Map beside the Marker has not changed." => showing a title beside the Marker is not an OSMBonusPack feature. You have an issue in your MarkerWithLabel class... If you provide its source code, we may have a look.

Comment: The readable format of the MarkerWithLabel class is above this message in an Answer.

Comment: Well, with the code, issue is obvious: you are not displaying the marker title, but your mLabel attribute. Just discard this mLabel and use marker title instead.